# passing values between uicontrols

Tags: matlab, user-interface, widget

I am just a beginner with MATLAB GUIs and just want to know simple ways to do this.

I have four widgets: 2 list `uicontrol`s, 1 push button `uicontrol`s, and 1 static text `uicontrol`.

```
 function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 x =get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value')  % getting the value from the popupmenu
 % doing something with it
 y=get(handles.popupmenu2, 'Value')  %  getting the value and processing it 
 % doing something with it

 total=x+y
 set(handles.text1, 'String', num2str(total))  % set to total...but
 % I really want it to be a string with a total.  like 'Your total is %s', total
```

Can you please help me set the text string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do:

```
str = sprintf('your total is %s', num2str(total)); % assuming total is a number, not a string
set(handles.statictext1, 'String', str); % replace handles.statictext1 by whatever the handle your static text box is
```